# I have a CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype extended, how can I acces to 'parent'

Tags: javascript, css

I have some custom methods for CSSStyleDeclaration.
I use it so :

```
A_OBJECT.style.method() ;
```

And the code is as simple as :

```
CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.method = function () {
x = this.left;
..... etc
}
```

My question is : How can I access to the 'object' element 'parent' of 'this' , that is : 'A_OBJECT' ???? Is it possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some cases, yes it is possible. For example, if you extend CanvasRenderingContext2d, then you can access `this.canvas` to get the "parent" canvas that the rendering context belongs to.

However, `CSSStyleDeclaration` has no such backreference. There is no way to find the element that your style declaration belongs to.

I would recommend extending `HTMLElement` instead, and using `this.style` to get the style object. Basically, start one level up.